# Recursive anti_join over list of dataframes

Tags: r

Given a list of data frames (each marked by a `time_range` column), I want to find the IDs that belong to each data frame but **do not** appear in the other two. I have fiddled around with recursive anti_join but didn't lead me anywhere close to the solution and it's probably overly complicated.

Data can be found by:

```r
df_list <- dget(file = "https://pastebin.com/raw/eFp3TSAP")
```

Comment: Do you need `reduce(df_list, anti_join, by= 'id')`

Comment: That will lead me to a single vector of IDs that appear just in one dataset. I am after 3 vectors (one for IDs that appear in df_a and not in df_b and df_c, another one for IDs that appear in df_b and not in df_a and df_c, etc.). Closer to the solution though.

Comment: It would be better to show the expected output so that it can be crosschecked

Comment: Can you show the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option with `anti_join/map`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map(seq_along(df_list), ~ anti_join(df_list[[.x]], 
          bind_rows(df_list[-.x]), by = 'id') %>% 
             pull(id))
#[[1]]
# [1] "5qOfTfMzTj2dvvpWKzIFk6" "2iQyHU4IeFpP9lU6OTtfKE" "6n6ot5JVa8YO9z82eNbvd8" "5l8VQNuIg0turYE1VtM9zV" "2ZvrvbQNrHKwjT7qfGFFUW"
# [6] "43mWhBXSflupNLuNjM5vff" "3oKRxpszQKUjjaHz388fVA" "54QMjE4toDfiCryzYWCpXX" "5szdY7KaSi7epwyffrbV8c" "65dGLGjkw3UbddUg2GKQoZ"
#[11] "23ymPLjbtAMzTJS2qRtQ8Z"

#[[2]]
# [1] "5Pa0BjjSDSiWuak0O1PbHL" "7M1FPw29m5FbicYzS2xdpi" "64mPnRMMeudAet0E62ypkx" "6ra4GIOgCZQZMOaUECftGN" "65C6Unk7nhg2aCnVuAPMo8"
# [6] "4aEnNH9PuU1HF3TsZTru54" "62sC6lUEWRjbFqXpMmOk4G" "7JCthCuu5Wmxv2avqVFolo" "75U40yZLLPglFgXbDVnmVs" "3AaY5O1qS0tcNPHwwMwplt"
#[11] "4G0XDEk7RbA4BBCTs917U9" "2i8ynmFv4qgRksyDlBgi6d" "0z6zRFzl5njXWLVAisXQBz"

#[[3]]
# [1] "7MhMgCo0Bl0Kukl93PZbYS" "3OsRAKCvk37zwYcnzRf5XF" "4Z8W4fKeB5YxbusRsdQVPb" "179BpmLkQCRIoU68Co80f5" "7jy3rLJdDQY21OgRLCZ9sD"
# [6] "6kBDZFXuLrZgHnvmPu9NsG" "3AA28KZvwAUcZuOKwyblJQ" "536BYVgOnRky0xjsPT96zl" "57dN52uHvrHOxijzpIgu3E" "6olE6TJLqED3rqDCT0FyPh"
#[11] "0k17h0D3J5VfsdmQ1iZtE9" "6kACVPfCOnqzgfEF5ryl0x" "4KWTAlx2RvbpseOGMEmROg" "54dqxLAclwu0QSaTwCyCaF" "6v8FB84lnmJs434UJf2Mrm"
#[16] "02uYdhMhCgdB49hZlYRm9o" "2exkZbmNqMKnT8LRWuxWgy" "2qk9voo8llSGYcZ6xrBzKx" "1w5Kfo2jwwIPruYS2UWh56" "6zvul52xwTWzilBZl6BUbT"
#[21] "0WwSkZ7LtFUFjGjMZBMt6T" "5Mhs3Eu8lU6sRCtRYsmABV" "1gR0gsQYfi6joyO1dlp76N" "3WaJSfKnzc65VDgmj2zU8B" "65EXuYHVoehCKqp0kOS6px"
#[26] "5RRPSRJpISAWEPOeSfYuhV" "1co4F2pPNH8JjTutZkmgSm" "6FQqZYVfTNQ1pCqfkwVFEa" "19HiWVd2g0XyJstBsbW2Qm"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `lapply` to loop along the list, and find the `setdiff` between each `id` column and the concatenation of all the other `id` columns, all in a base R one-liner:

```r
df_list <- dget(file = "https://pastebin.com/raw/eFp3TSAP")

lapply(1:3, function(i) setdiff(df_list[[i]]$id, do.call(rbind, df_list[-i])$id))
#> [[1]]
#>  [1] "5qOfTfMzTj2dvvpWKzIFk6" "2iQyHU4IeFpP9lU6OTtfKE" "6n6ot5JVa8YO9z82eNbvd8"
#>  [4] "5l8VQNuIg0turYE1VtM9zV" "2ZvrvbQNrHKwjT7qfGFFUW" "43mWhBXSflupNLuNjM5vff"
#>  [7] "3oKRxpszQKUjjaHz388fVA" "54QMjE4toDfiCryzYWCpXX" "5szdY7KaSi7epwyffrbV8c"
#> [10] "65dGLGjkw3UbddUg2GKQoZ" "23ymPLjbtAMzTJS2qRtQ8Z"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>  [1] "5Pa0BjjSDSiWuak0O1PbHL" "7M1FPw29m5FbicYzS2xdpi" "64mPnRMMeudAet0E62ypkx"
#>  [4] "6ra4GIOgCZQZMOaUECftGN" "65C6Unk7nhg2aCnVuAPMo8" "4aEnNH9PuU1HF3TsZTru54"
#>  [7] "62sC6lUEWRjbFqXpMmOk4G" "7JCthCuu5Wmxv2avqVFolo" "75U40yZLLPglFgXbDVnmVs"
#> [10] "3AaY5O1qS0tcNPHwwMwplt" "4G0XDEk7RbA4BBCTs917U9" "2i8ynmFv4qgRksyDlBgi6d"
#> [13] "0z6zRFzl5njXWLVAisXQBz"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>  [1] "7MhMgCo0Bl0Kukl93PZbYS" "3OsRAKCvk37zwYcnzRf5XF" "4Z8W4fKeB5YxbusRsdQVPb"
#>  [4] "179BpmLkQCRIoU68Co80f5" "7jy3rLJdDQY21OgRLCZ9sD" "6kBDZFXuLrZgHnvmPu9NsG"
#>  [7] "3AA28KZvwAUcZuOKwyblJQ" "536BYVgOnRky0xjsPT96zl" "57dN52uHvrHOxijzpIgu3E"
#> [10] "6olE6TJLqED3rqDCT0FyPh" "0k17h0D3J5VfsdmQ1iZtE9" "6kACVPfCOnqzgfEF5ryl0x"
#> [13] "4KWTAlx2RvbpseOGMEmROg" "54dqxLAclwu0QSaTwCyCaF" "6v8FB84lnmJs434UJf2Mrm"
#> [16] "02uYdhMhCgdB49hZlYRm9o" "2exkZbmNqMKnT8LRWuxWgy" "2qk9voo8llSGYcZ6xrBzKx"
#> [19] "1w5Kfo2jwwIPruYS2UWh56" "6zvul52xwTWzilBZl6BUbT" "0WwSkZ7LtFUFjGjMZBMt6T"
#> [22] "5Mhs3Eu8lU6sRCtRYsmABV" "1gR0gsQYfi6joyO1dlp76N" "3WaJSfKnzc65VDgmj2zU8B"
#> [25] "65EXuYHVoehCKqp0kOS6px" "5RRPSRJpISAWEPOeSfYuhV" "1co4F2pPNH8JjTutZkmgSm"
#> [28] "6FQqZYVfTNQ1pCqfkwVFEa" "19HiWVd2g0XyJstBsbW2Qm"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>